# Real time Android kernel or application development

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-ndk, real-time

I would like to ask you if there is a way to create real time applications in Android. I know that Android is does not support real time applications so I wonder if there is an alternative way of accomplishing it. Can it be done using another (more real time) kernel?

Is there a way to go down and program the Linux kernel in Android? I do not know if Native code can be more useful. The application should be able to control the camera's led as fast as possible and there is no Native API provided by Google. Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Based on your prior question about LED, I think you'll either have to go the route of a custom ROM or realize that you are trying to make a car fly. And if its the Camera LED/Flash - then you are in the deep world of the hardware drivers. One suggestion is to offload the strobe LED to a custom USB hardware which can be called via the USB Accessory API.

Answer (score 2):

Android as an OS cannot guarantee your userspace application any real-time performance.  Android userspace is quite different than typical Linux userspace which hardly matters because neither is suitable for hard real-time requirements.  Writing native code may help a bit, but still not gain you any guarantees of response or timeliness.

You may be capable of achieving pseudo real-time performance by making modifications to the kernel.  Increasing the amount of preemption in the kernel (such as the modifications made by the PREEMPT_RT patch) and implementing your real-time code as an interrupt handler routine invoked by a high priority interrupt may allow you to achieve response times in 10s to 100s of microseconds.  Unfortunately, there are several issues with this approach:

- Although the Linux kernel in Android isn't enormously modified, its different enough that existing Linux real-time patches are likely rendered incompatible.  You'd need to go about patching a lot of the Android kernel additions from scratch.
- An Android app cannot simply install a modified kernel on an Android device.  The kernel would have to be distributed separately and flashed on an unlocked device.  This is quite impractical for most applications; however, it may be reasonable for purpose-built systems.

Finally, if you have the option of developing & interfacing custom hardware, you could easily offload the real-time LED control to a simple microcontroller.  Most devices have interfaces available which could be connected to a microcontroller.  And of course if you're building your own device then you have many options for interfacing a microcontroller.